# Android- adding view to layout causing layout to be in front of ActionBar

Tags: android, view, android-actionbar, popupwindow

I have a view in which I'm creating a `PopupWindow`. In this `PopupWindow`, I have a text box (`EditText`). When clicking to edit the text, the keyboard opens and the whole view goes up, but the top of the view goes **under** the action bar view smoothly. So far so good.

I now have added an empty `GridView` without any further configuration to the `PopupWindow`, and now the same scenario happens but the whole top part of the view goes **on top** of the action bar view and not smooth (the popup becomes a mess, when keyboard disappears the popup location changes for couple of seconds and there are "leftovers" from the keyboard for a second). It also happens with `ListView`.

I want the top part of the view to go under the 'ActionBar` smoothly, as it should.

Any ideas?

**UPDATE:** By adding the `GridView` programatically I partially solved it on a couple of devices, but on some devices it's still happens.

Displaying the `popupwindow`:

```
 pView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_packbuild, (ViewGroup)mainActivity.findViewById(R.layout.activity_main));

 pw = new PopupWindow(
            pView,
            ma.f.getView().getMeasuredWidth(),
            ma.f.getView().getMeasuredHeight(),
            true);

 pw.showAtLocation(mainActivity.getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.content), Gravity.BOTTOM, 0, 0);
```

GOOD:

[image]

BAD:

[image]

Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/lID">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/rID"
    android:background="@drawable/back5">


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="125px"
        android:layout_height="200px"
        android:id="@+id/mImageView"
        android:background="@drawable/com_facebook_picker_default_separator_color"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="300dp" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_below="@+id/mImageView"
        android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/lButton"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/rButton" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="125px"
        android:layout_height="200px"
        android:id="@+id/imageViewRR"
        android:background="@drawable/com_facebook_picker_default_separator_color"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/mImageView"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/mImageView"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="125px"
        android:layout_height="200px"
        android:id="@+id/imageViewLL"
        android:background="@drawable/com_facebook_picker_default_separator_color"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/mImageView"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/mImageView"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:id="@+id/lButton"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageViewLL"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/imageViewLL" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:id="@+id/rButton"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/lButton"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imageViewRR"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/imageViewRR"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:id="@+id/picButton"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/galleryButton"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/editText"
        android:background="@drawable/camera2" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:id="@+id/videoButton"
        android:background="@drawable/video"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/galleryButton"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="125px"
        android:layout_height="200px"
        android:id="@+id/imageViewR"
        android:background="@drawable/com_facebook_picker_default_separator_color"
        android:layout_above="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/sendButon"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/sendButon" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="125px"
        android:layout_height="200px"
        android:id="@+id/imageViewL"
        android:background="@drawable/com_facebook_picker_default_separator_color"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/mImageView"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:id="@+id/galleryButton"
        android:background="@drawable/gallery"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/rButton"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imageViewR" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="100px"
        android:layout_height="100px"
        android:id="@+id/toButton"
        android:layout_above="@+id/imageViewR"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/picButton"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/imageViewL"
        android:background="@drawable/fbfriends2"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imageViewLL"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/imageViewLL"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:id="@+id/sendButon"
        android:background="@drawable/go"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/toButton"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/editText" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:id="@+id/plusButtonL"
        android:background="@drawable/plusp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/videoButton"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageViewLL" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:id="@+id/minusButtonR"
        android:background="@drawable/minusp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/videoButton"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageViewRR" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:id="@+id/plusButton"
        android:background="@drawable/plusp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/videoButton"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:id="@+id/minusButton"
        android:background="@drawable/minusp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/videoButton"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="300dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I'm adding the `GridView` programmatically:

```
 gv=new GridView(ma);
            List<Student> hhh=new ArrayList<Student>();
            if (FriendPickerApplication.selectedUsers!=null) {
                if (FriendPickerApplication.selectedUsers.size() > 0) {
                    for (GraphUser gu : FriendPickerApplication.selectedUsers) {
                        hhh.add(new Student("name", gu.getId()));
                    }
                }
            }

            StudentAdapter sta=new StudentAdapter(ma,hhh);

            //gv=(GridView)pView.findViewById(R.id.gridView2);
            gv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            MainActivity.wantedPicSize=ma.screenWidth/12; //6
            int wantedSize=MainActivity.wantedPicSize+2; //10

            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams relativeParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
            relativeParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.LEFT_OF, btnSend.getId());
            relativeParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF,picFriends.getId());
            relativeParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_TOP, picFriends.getId());
            relativeParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_BOTTOM, picFriends.getId());
            gv.setLayoutParams(relativeParams);
            gv.setPadding(5,0,5,0);
            ((RelativeLayout)pView.findViewById(R.id.rID)).addView(gv);

            ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);//gv.getLayoutParams();

            relativeParams.height = wantedSize+(int)(wantedSize/5); //this is in pixels
            relativeParams.width = (int)(ma.screenWidth/3.0);//gv.getLayoutParams().width; //(int)( ( ((ma.screenWidth*3)/4)/wantedSize )*wantedSize );

            gv.setColumnWidth(wantedSize); //+width betwen profiles
            gv.setVerticalSpacing(5);
            //gv.setNumColumns((int)((screenWidth/2)/100));
            gv.setNumColumns((relativeParams.width/wantedSize));
            System.out.print("COLUMNSSSSSSSSSS- "+(relativeParams.width/wantedSize));
            gv.setLayoutParams(relativeParams);
            gv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            gv.setAdapter(sta);
```

Comment: could you please post some screenshots ? I have difficulties trying to picture how the problem looks like, if possible post one where your `popupwindow` works are expected (on some devices as you say) and one where it doesn't

Comment: I've added the good and bad screenshots.

Comment: Could you please provide your layout?. Also it could be better to use Dialog/DialogFragment

Comment: What are you using to display your PopupWindow? There are a few different ways to position and/or clip your popup that may alleviate or at least work-around your issue.

Comment: I've added they way how I'm displaying the `popupwindow`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with the answer posted by Pasquale Anatriello. Though u can
You can try different methods :

```
mPopUpWindow.showAsDropDown(anchor);
mPopUpWindow.showAsDropDown(anchor, xoff, yoff);
mPopUpWindow.showAtLocation(parent, gravity, x, y);
```

I suggest you should let popUp draw only after Action Bar, take y axis offset and gravity top, say: yOffset is Equivalent to actionbar height, if you have action bar ~ height x 10% of device height , [layout_weight = 1.0].
Even if it didn't work out create a custom View [say Linear Layout] that appears and disappears and acts like popup a window and give u flexibility as u want,handle clicks by yourself, make it like a toggle,  see code for animation::

```
Animation fadeInAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(v.getContext(), android.R.anim.fade_in);
        fadeInAnimation.setDuration(10);
        v.startAnimation(fadeInAnimation);

  Animation fadeOutAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(v.getContext(), android.R.anim.fade_out);
        fadeOutAnimation.setDuration(10);
        v.startAnimation(fadeOutAnimation);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem here is the popup window.
There is no way to make it go under the actionbar since the actionbar is displayed in another window that is below the new window you are creating. moreover using a popup window for that complex layout is never going to perform efficiently. Have you thought of wrapping your map and the layout you are putting in the popup window in a custom layout? That would probably be the easier solution

Comment: `using a popup window for that complex layout is never going to perform efficiently` - why?